# How to add an elimination rule to auto?

Tags: isabelle

Here are arithmetic expressions from the "Concrete Semantics" (section 3.1):

```
type_synonym vname = string
datatype aexp = N int | V vname | Plus aexp aexp

fun asimp_const :: "aexp ⇒ aexp" where
  "asimp_const (N n) = N n"
| "asimp_const (V x) = V x"
| "asimp_const (Plus a1 a2) =
    (case (asimp_const a1, asimp_const a2)
      of (N n1, N n2) ⇒ N (n1 + n2)
       | (b1, b2) ⇒ Plus b1 b2)"
```

`asimp_const` folds `Plus (N n1) (N n2)` subexpressions to `N (n1 + n2)`.

The following function checks that an expression doesn't contain any `Plus (N n1) (N n2)`:

```
fun optimal :: "aexp ⇒ bool" where
  "optimal (N n) = True"
| "optimal (V x) = True"
| "optimal (Plus a1 a2) = (case (a1, a2)
    of (N n1, N n2) ⇒ False
     | (b1, b2) ⇒ optimal b1 ∧ optimal b2)"
```

I'm trying to prove the following lemma:

```
lemma "optimal (asimp_const a)"
  apply (induct a)
  apply simp
  apply simp
  by (erule optimal.elims; erule optimal.elims; simp)
```

The problem is that I have to apply `optimal.elims` explicitly.

I can declare `optimal.elims` as an elimination rule and then the proof reduces to the following:

```
declare optimal.elims [elim!]

lemma "optimal (asimp_const a)"
  by (induct a; auto)
```

But is it possible to add `optimal.elims` to `auto` without declaring it as an elimintation rule?

The following doesn't apply `optimal.elims`:

```
lemma "optimal (asimp_const a)"
  by (induct a; auto elim: optimal.elims)
```

And the following is stuck:

```
lemma "optimal (asimp_const a)"
  by (induct a; auto elim!: optimal.elims)
```

Can I add elimination rules to `simp` instead of `auto`?

Comment: The last variant (that is the one with `elim!`) works for me.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, it works. Maybe I did something wrong, that it was stuck.

Comment: Additionally, you can use `fastforce elim:` instead of `auto elim!:`. `simp` will usually not work with intro/elim-rules.

Comment: I will turn this informal discussion into a proper answer for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last variant, that is, `auto elim!:` actually works. However, by using `elim!` you are forcing `auto` to assume that `optimal.elims` are safe rules. A better alternative to explicitly pass `optimal.elims` as elimination rules for this specific case is `fastforce elim:`.

Regarding your last question, `simp` will usually not work with introduction/elimination rules but only with simplification rules.